# Is it possible to receive raw ethernet frames in Linux without specifying an interface?

Tags: go, networking, linux-kernel

I'm using mdlayhers (golang) libraries to handle raw ethernet frames to receive and process LLDP packets on a networking device. I'd like to monitor a large number of interfaces (up to 128) for LLDP frames.

In Linux I [don't believe it's required](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html) to specify an interface to capture device data, but I could be wrong. Is it possible to receive raw ethernet frames across all interfaces by, for example, binding to `AF_PACKET` in go? I.e. Is there way to specify a wildcard interface in `raw.ListenPacket` or am I best creating a new goroutine for each interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. I believe this is what you are looking for:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    fd, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_PACKET, syscall.SOCK_RAW, int(htons(syscall.ETH_P_ALL)))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "syscall socket: %s", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Make a 32KB buffer
    buf := make([]byte, 1<<16)
    for {
        len, sockaddr, err := syscall.Recvfrom(fd, buf, 0)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "syscall recvfrom: %s", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        if llsa, ok := sockaddr.(*syscall.SockaddrLinklayer); ok {
            inter, err := net.InterfaceByIndex(llsa.Ifindex)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "interface from ifindex: %s", err.Error())
                os.Exit(1)
            }
            fmt.Print(inter.Name + ": ")
        }

        fmt.Printf("% X\n", buf[:len])
    }
}

// htons converts a short (uint16) from host-to-network byte order.
func htons(i uint16) uint16 {
    return (i<<8)&0xff00 | i>>8
}
```

Comment: I believe OP already knows that this is possible with raw syscalls, and is trying to understand if it's possible to also do this using [the `raw.ListenPacket` method of this package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mdlayher/raw#ListenPacket).

Comment: Thanks for this - more or less however what I miss with the raw syscall is the interface the packet has arrived from which is needed in this example

Comment: Ah, we have this info, it is the second return val of Recvfrom, I discarded it, but you can use it to lookup the network interface. I have updated the example

Comment: Thanks @DylanReimerink I had noticed that after playing around with your code - great example and very helpful. Thank you for answering

Comment: @DylanReimerink as I continue to experiment with this it appears as if in order for AF_PACKET to be received another application needs to be listening for it - it's not like a catch all. Is there a way to achieve this with your example?

Comment: That is strange, it should. Are you sending the packets locally or from another machine? `man packet` says the following: `SOCK_RAW  packets  are  passed  to and from the device driver without any changes in the packet data`. So if a packet never touches the device driver for some reason we might not see it? Also `SOCK_DGRAM operates on a slightly higher level.` Maybe you have more luck with `SOCK_DGRAM` instread of `SOCK_RAW`, keep in mind that with DGRAM the physical header is striped